# Can I use repo upload to push code and create code review in my private repo in AOSP

Tags: android, android-source

I've set up an AOSP project locally and I managed to replace some of the modules in AOSP with my private repo in Github via manifest.xml.

However, I'm confused about the `repo upload` command here, according to https://source.android.com/docs/setup/contribute/submit-patches#upload-to-gerrit, using `repo upload` Repo will provide with the URL of a new page on https://android-review.googlesource.com/. But I don't want to expose my changes to this website since they are private repo in my Github.

What should I do about it? Do I have an alternative way to push the code and request a review automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'repo upload' command is used to send changes to the Gerrit Code
Review system. Github is different with Gerrit about reviewing. So you can not upload the changes to GitHub with repo upload.

And you can use git command to push the commit to the Github. Github use the ["Pull Request"](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/about-pull-requests) to [review changes](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/reviewing-changes-in-pull-requests). It can be done by [Github CLI](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request)

Comment: Thanks, so currently I will choose to use repo forall -c "git push" and create pull requests manually in Github webpage.